# How to fix 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (8)

Tags: python, mysql, django, pandas

I want to run the database with mysql.connector to create a dataframe, but I caught the problem 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (8) after running with python manage.py runserver.

associationrule.py

```bash
import os
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

con = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='mariadb', host='db', database='mariadb', port='9051')

dfParcel = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM LoanParcel", con)
dfDurable = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM LoanDurable", con)
```

docker-compose.py

```bash
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mariadb
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mariadb
      - MYSQL_USER=mariadb
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mariadb
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    ports:
      - 9051:3306
    volumes:
      - "mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql"  

  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=mariadb+mariadbconnector://user:mariadb@db:9051/mariadb
    ports:
      - "9052:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      
volumes:
  mysqldata:
```

Comment: What is db in `host='db'` ? A host is IP or domain name of the server you wish to connect.